# Field update doesn't work when changing type parameters

Tags: record, isabelle

I find that the `record ⦇ field := value ⦈` notation does not work as expected when I use it to change `record`'s type parameter in the process. To clarify what I mean, consider the following example:

```
theory Scratch imports 
  Main 
begin

record 'a john =
  apple :: 'a
  banana :: int

definition f :: "nat john ⇒ bool john"
where
  "f j ≡ j ⦇ apple := True ⦈"

definition f_fixed :: "nat john ⇒ bool john"
where
  "f_fixed j ≡ ⦇ apple = True, banana = banana j ⦈"

end
```

The definition for `f` is not accepted due to a type error. It seems that I cannot use a field update to change the type of the underlying record. I'm mildly surprised at this, because `f_fixed` looks pretty similar, but works absolutely fine. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a known restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known restriction.

The syntax `j⦇ apple := True ⦈` is shorthand for `john.apple_update (λ_. True) j`, where the function `apply_update` has type:

```
('a ⇒ 'a) ⇒ 'a john ⇒ 'a john
```

(The first parameter is a function that gets passed the old value of `apple` and returns a new value. Because you are unconditionally updating the field to `True`, your function is `(λ_. True)`.)

The type of this function prevents the type `'a` from changing during the update. What you presumably are looking for is an update function with the following type:

```
('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ 'a john ⇒ 'b john
```

One possible complication of emitting such functions would be in the following scenario:

```
record 'a john =
  apple :: 'a
  banana :: 'a
```

What should the type of `apple_update` be? You can't change the type of `apple` without simultaneously changing the type of `banana`.

Again, there are no *technical* reasons why such functions couldn't be emitted by the record package, it is just a matter of determining what the correct functions to emit would be in all the various corner cases.